# Communication between C# and Java Sockets halting?

Tags: java, c#, sockets, networking

I'm using sockets to communicate between C# and Java. However, My stream in C# keeps freezing whenever I try to read from it. I'm wondering if someone might be able to help me out.

Java Code -

```
public void Send(String message) throws Exception {
    sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 2913);
    PrintStream PS = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
    PS.println(message);
}
```

C# Code -

```
private static void Listen(){
    serverSocket.Start ();

    while (true) {
        TcpClient Client = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient ();
        NetworkStream stream = Client.GetStream ();
        byte[] read = new byte[10025];
        stream.Read (read, 0, (int)Client.ReceiveBufferSize);
        Client.GetStream().Flush();
        string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString (read);

        //Output data from client

        Client.Close();
    }
}
```

I've managed to ensure that the client is connecting, and that all of the C# code is executing up to the point where it calls

```
stream.Read();
```

I'm wondering if someone might know why it is halting on stream.Read();. Is my java trying to send the message before C# has a chance to listen to it? If so, how would I fix that. I've tried using

```
while(!sock.isConnected()) Thread.sleep(1);
```

in my Java, but it didn't help.

Comment: Why are you using Client.ReceiveBufferSize in your read operation just use read.Length as in this example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @PhilipStuyck  fixed it with my answer below, but thanks a lot for the input. I'm rather new to networking with sockets. I've alsways used some sort of API in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing it by using this for my C# function.

```
private static void Listen(){
    serverSocket.Start ();

    while (true) {
        TcpClient Client = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient ();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Client.GetStream ());
        string dataFromClient = sr.ReadLine();
        //Output Data From Client 
        Client.Close();
    }
}
```

I guess using the stream reader instead of trying to read the bytes myself fixed it.

Comment: It should not make a difference, take a look at the example in msdn, it is not using readline.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck  think the issue may have been what you were saying earlier. I was using the wrong length when reading the bytes back. But now since the StreamReader does it for me, I don't have to worry about it.